# How to animate collapse inside directive that use ng-if to be showed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using angularJS with AngularUI API.

My problem is when I use a directive that contains **collapse**.

What happens:

My directive initialize correctly, but **don't animate** when I set collapse to false and I need the animation.

My template using directive:

```
<div ng-if="showDirective">
    <my-form></my-form>
</div>
```

My directive:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('myForm', MyForm);

 function MyForm() {
        return {
            controllerAs: 'gr',
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: false,
            templateUrl: 'myForm.html',
            scope: {
                cancel: '&?',
            },
            link:link,
            controller: controller,
        }

        function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
          angular.element(document).ready(function(){
            ctrl.isCollapse = false;
          });
        }

        function controller($scope) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.isCollapse = true;
        }
    }
})()
```

My template of directive:

```
<div>
    <div collapse="gr.isCollapse">
        //A lot of code....
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should take a look at $ngAnimate module https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!!!

I just set **isCollapsed** to false using **$timeout**:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
  $timeout(function(){
    ctrl.isCollapse = false;
  }, 0);
}
```

So collapse work after the load of directive.